# XStream parser empty tag for null values

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xstream

I'm using XStream parser. I wants to get an empty tag in place of null values for a variable. How do I achieve this?

Example:

```
class Person{
    private String name;
    private String age;
}

Person person = new Person("Joe", null);
```

I'm getting this,

```
<Person>
    <name>Joe</name>
</Person>
```

I need this,

```
<Person>
    <name>Joe</name>
    <age></age>
</Person>
```

Comment: Try to set empty string.

Answer (score 0):

If it only concerns strings, initialise them with "", not with null.

So instead of:

```
Person person = new Person("Joe", null);
```

Try:

```
Person person = new Person("Joe", "");
```

Also, make sure to take a look at: [XStream serialize null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066360/xstream-serialize-null-values)

Comment: If its two fields then its ok. I have 12 classes which has around 30 fields in each class aprox. I can't set to each variable. Is there any configuration for that whichever variable is null it should set an empty string like that?

Comment: Corry, couldn't really find/think of any other way... Maybe this [Correct way to represent null XML elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774192/what-is-the-correct-way-to-represent-null-xml-elements) or this [XML serialization, hide null values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818513/xml-serialization-hide-null-values) might help provide any help?

Comment: Actually, what Saulius Next commented on your question seems to work, but that's the same solution as I have provided, but which looks neater.

How about providing such default values in the getters and setters? Could you extend a bit on what your situation is?